# Link android and iOS application to a common link using Facebook

Tags: android, ios, facebook

There is an application that I have developed in iOS and Android. 
A *Facebook Share* is done from within the application, and appears on the user's news feed. 
I want to  link the news feed  with the respective links in Android play store, and iOS app store. Based on the user's device the appropriate link be shown.

Is this possible ? Deep linking, does not seem to solve this problem.

Example:

1. From the android/iOS application, app-user Shares "I just used this
   awesome app".
2. It appears on his friends' news feed with this link pointed
   **SOMEWHERE**.
3. I want to point this **SOMEWHERE** to the Android play store/iOS app store, depending on the device, from which user is ccessing facebook.
4. If the user is an iPhone user, the news feed link would point it to the APP STORE,
   else if he is Android user, he is shown Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

it definitely is possible but you will have to use the facebook sdk:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/link-to-your-native-app/

hope this helps